# How to use the 'at' command on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

How can we schedule processes using the 'at command on cygwin'? 'The at command has been deprecated on cygwin'is the error I got on trying out the 'at command.' Are there any equivalent commands in Cygwin for at and batch?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I used `schtasks.exe` in the same way I'd use `at`

```
schtasks /create /tn "Run Meter" /ru System /tr "nssm.exe restart Meter" /sc once /st 12:00
```

is functionally identical to

```
at 12:00 <<<"nssm.exe restart Meter"
```

Answer (score -1):

AT isn't a Cygwin-specific program, it's part of Windows. The complete message says:

`The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead.`

You can run schtasks from cygwin, too. For immediate help with schtasks, from cygwin you can type:

`schtasks /?`

Otherwise, Google is your friend. :)

Comment: Google is my friend. Windows is my enemy. All of my efforts to "run a command with arguments once at a specified time" have failed. `schtasks.exe` is NOT a suitable replacement for the unix `at` command. The later is actually usable.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky no argument here, although it is possible to run a command with args from a scheduled task ... Looks like they are working on background tasks in WSL (Bash on Windows 10), so that might be another way to get the experience desired.

Comment: That you for replying. It reminded me to post my working solution so that others might benefit.